# Snowflake: Ranking row numbers into groups in intervals of 7 (ie: 1-7 is assigned 1, 8-14 is assigned 2, 15- 21 etc) partitioned by a column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is my desired output:
[image]

Row no. is already via a COUNT windows function partitioned by group.

The only way I can think of is to use CASE WHEN, but then I'll have to write so many lines of code and as the data is stream, I'll have to constantly alter and update the code to reflect the new data. For example, one group has over 2,000 rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t0(grp) as (
    select * from values
    ('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),('A'),
    ('A'),('A'),('A'),('B'),('B'),('B'))
select
    grp,
    row_number() over (partition by grp order by 1) as row_no,
    floor((row_no-1)/7)+1 as interval
from t0
```

| GRP | ROW_NO | INTERVAL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 3 | 1 |
| A | 4 | 1 |
| A | 5 | 1 |
| A | 6 | 1 |
| A | 7 | 1 |
| A | 8 | 2 |
| A | 9 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 1 |

Comment: Works. Thank you. Just so I fully understand: why the +1 on the penultimate line?

Comment: Also, looking at your output, row 7 should also be 1. Like inclusive. For my dataset, it works perfectly past interval 1 but for 1 itself, it seems to be up to 6 rather than 6.

Comment: I solved this by adding 0.01 to 7, but not sure if there's a way to fix it without doing this.

Comment: Yes, I missed that on row 7. Corrected above. The inclusion of the -1 is needed to get row 7 in the first interval. The +1  is needed to start with an interval of 1 instead of an interval of 0.

Comment: OK, thanks. I understand the latter. Sorry, why does the inclusion of -1 solve the aforementioned problem (that affected row 7)?